# GeoJson is rendered correctly but without the requested color

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, leaflet, geojson

I have the following method "ajax_geojson" that produces the geo json:

```
    geo_json = [ {"type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "id":  c_name,
                        "marker-color": "#f80530",
                        "marker-size": "medium",
                        "marker-symbol": "",
                        "popupContent":  content , 
                        }, 
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [lon, lat] }}
                    for c_name,content, lon,lat in zip(country_name, content, longtitude, latitude) ]     

   return JsonResponse(geo_json, safe=False)
```

the javascript renders this with a jQuery:

```
              $.ajax({
                url: '/research/ajax_geojson',
                success: function (collection) 
                {                           
                   L.geoJson(collection, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);

                   function onEachFeature(feature, layer) 
                   {
                        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) 
                        {
                            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent); 
                        }  
                    }                       

                }
        });
```

While the markers are shown on the map precisely as requested, the color doesn't seem to take any effect (#f80530 is red)

My question: is there anything I need to add to the javascript under the  layer.bindPopup? I was under the impression that defining the color in the geo_json should present itself in the map. What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try adding a "style" object following "geometry" in your geo_json settings object:

```
    geo_json = [ {"type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "id":  c_name,
                        "marker-color": "#f80530",
                        "marker-size": "medium",
                        "marker-symbol": "",
                        "popupContent":  content , 
                        }, 
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [lon, lat] },
                    "style":{
                      //all SVG styles allowed
                      "fill":"red",
                      "stroke-width":"3",
                      "fill-opacity":0.6 }}
                    for c_name,content, lon,lat in zip(country_name, content, longtitude, latitude) ]     

   return JsonResponse(geo_json, safe=False)
```

Comment: nope. I tried to play with the style before. Didn't do the trick :-(